# How do I fix vlc?: Lines in every video (elementary os)

Tags: elementary-os, vlc

every video is happening this :
[image: print1]

and in vlc there is no option to enable hardware acceleration

Messages (vlc) : avcodec info: Using Intel i965 driver for Intel(R) Haswell Desktop

i have an amd gpu btw

Comment: Most likely decoder problem or some video format problem. Different player?

Answer (score 1):

i found a solution, i installed smplayer and now everything is working fine

Comment: Is vlc working?

Comment: no, it doesn't working

Answer (score 0):

For vlc try to use vaapi and libva-intel-driver,[in this page some info](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Hardware_video_acceleration#Intel)..they are for archlinux,try to adapt to elementary os(search on repos,etc)
After install(if not already installed..check first),in the vlc options enable vaapi or vdpau.

Comment: still don't working